# Spaces around display math when using setspace

Tags: line-spacing, setspace, displaystyle

I'm using setspace package in the following way:

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
```

It works well, mostly very nice result, but the spaces around display math formulae had enlarged too and now they look too large. Is there a standard way to fix it, so that spacing around display math are normal again?

Comment: You can give a minimum working example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can say

```
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
```

or `\setdisplayskipstretch` to a different value than the default (which is equal to `\baselinestretch`, such as

```
\setdisplayskipstretch{1.5}
```